# How to calculate frequencies over deciles

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, frequency, quantile

Everything is recorded in a cash register database table, `[dbo].[festival]`. Each row in `[dbo].[festival]` is an order row from a festival participant. We have the following columns:

`[ticket_no]` `int` - Each participant has a unique entry ticket number, although this is not a PK since many participants order many rounds before they stagger home or are carried out.

`[price]` `float` - The price tags of the various kinds and sizes of beer served.

`[quantity]` `int` - The number of beers ordered at that price.

Now I want understand the participants better. I want the total sales of beer divided into 10 equal chunks, with the number of participants making up each decile and the absolute spending range of the decile, in rising order. Something like:

```sql
[Decile] / [Lower end of range] / [Upper end of range] / [No of participants] / [Total sales in this decile]
```

So, given total sales in the event of 100.000, the first two (of ten) rows could be something like:

```sql
1 / 2.50 / 4.75 / 3104 / 10.000 

2 / 4.75 / 6.50 / 1905 / 10.000
...
```

Meaning 3104 participants with the lowest spending range from 2.50 up to 4.75 stood for the first 10k of the 100k beer sales, then there were 1905 participants who spent between... etc.

How do you solve this in SQL? I failed to adapt John Cappelletti's solution to the previous problem.

Comment: FYI, `float` is a poor choice of a data type for something called `price`, which I *assume* is a monetary value. Currency isn't represented in base 2 values; it's base 10. a `decimal` is a *far* better data type choice.

Comment: I wish we could use rep to +10 a comment instead of +1.

Comment: @Greyhound  maybe if you provided some sample data that clearly defines your question and your expected results of that sample data, then perhaps you will find that people are more willing to help you.  Just a thought :-)

Comment: Yeah, this is kind of like those word problem tests nobody ever did well at in grade school. Sample data and desired results please. See: https://sqlblog.org/ask

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I managed to find a guy who is not only used to translate real-life problems into code (common work requirement) but who is also more interested in helping and solving problems than farming rep and shooting down posts.

Here is his solution to my problem that works well enough for my purposes. Since nobody actually managed to solve the problem, who knows, maybe you will learn from it? Just trying to be helpful.

```
;WITH cte AS (
    SELECT SUM(price * quantity) spending, ticket_no
    FROM festival
    GROUP BY ticket_no
    )
SELECT MIN(spending) min_spending, MAX(spending) max_spending, SUM(participant) tot_participants, SUM(participant * spending) tot_spending
FROM (
    SELECT
        MAX(spending) spending
        ,COUNT(*) participant
        ,SUM(spending * COUNT(*)) OVER (ORDER BY spending) AS cumulative
        ,((SUM(spending * COUNT(*)) OVER (ORDER BY spending) / SUM(spending * COUNT(*)) OVER () * 100 / 10) AS cumulative_percent
    FROM cte
    GROUP BY spending
    ) a
GROUP BY CAST(cumulative_percent - 0.000001 AS int) --To avoid an 11th decile in my sample
```

Note that the deciles won't be exactly the same size (he doubted there is a workaround) but it's close enough for my purposes.